# Barcode scanner and input fields, replace new line call to tab call?

Tags: html, forms, barcode

So barcode scanners end each scan with a carriage return, which messes up forms by submitting them. Is it possible to change this so that it calls a tab instead (thus moving to the next input field)?

I did a find a solution here that does that, but it manually focused on each input using their id's. The number of inputs I have is variable so I cannot do that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.  There are 2 ways:

1. reprogram the barcode reader to send the `TAB` key instead of a carriage return after reading a barcode
2. use javascript to capture the submit event and inspect the form state.  Either prevent submit and move focus to the next field or allow the submit event to continue based on the form state.

Comment: I cannot do #2 since the number of inputs increases as the user inputs more items, so I wouldn't know how to target the next input.

As for #1, I know with JQuery I can prevent it from doing default, but can I make it fire another event?

Comment: Use jQuery to select the next input field, relative to the field for current submit event. Or find the next empty field in the form.

Comment: You can either let the original submit event continue, or stop the original event and send another form submit with something like `$(event.currentTarget).submit()`

Comment: If I use `$(":input").keypress(function(event)` to catch the event, and my inputs are generate with  `var newRow = initRow.clone().removeAttr('id').addClass('new').insertBefore(initRow),` it does not seem to work on them. The form still submits. The code works because I have other forms and it works on them.

Comment: The form submit event is getting sent by the barcode reading sending a carriage return after it reads a barcode.  You need to capture the submit event to prevent form submission.

Comment: I know and I already can do that. it just doesn't work on input fields generated by jQuery, only on ones that I have hard coded.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26724/discussion-between-teddy-and-gta0004)

Comment: Eh I solved it. I just had to expand the range of the event catcher to the div that would contain all of my cloned inputs