# program a barcode scanner to append TAB rather than ENTER

Tags: php, mysql, barcode-scanner

I'm developing an web based Application using PHP & MySQL. My application requires the user to   shot a Barcode Scanner to an AUTOFOCUS-ed field in my product entry form, after this AUTOFOCUS-ed field is filled with code shot form the BARCODE Scanner, the form presents a list of similarly coded products (THe products I'm scanning could have similar Barcodes but different Prices), out of which the user needs to select a particular product.

The Scanner I'm using is TVS BSC-101 STAR Scanner, which is most popular in India. **The problem is that it is reading ENTER as appending code and I need to program it to append TAB** (or something that emulates the TAB button on Keyboard) otherwise it is just not moving to the next field where the user based on the code scanned, gets a list of similarly coded products list.

Can anyone help me out in here, appreciate your help.

Comment: So, you're looking for JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15556790/2186023 second approach might be more feasible for you than to override the outputs of the scanner itself

Comment: [THE BS-C 101 Star MANUAL](http://www.tvs-e.in/pos/drivers/BS-C101-Star-Programming-Guide.pdf): look for `Message Terminator`, you should be able to simply scan the configuration code to enter configuration mode then choose the termination character you want and then scan the end configuration code and be done;)

Answer (score 0):

reading enter should trigger a page reload, isn't it?
if that's the case, implement a PHP function that read the barcode and output the similar ones.

otherwise you could inhibit the enter keypress via javascript and simulate a tab keypress